# Downloading Python Package with latest version

Tags: python

I am slightly new to Python, but attempting to import a package (`bartpy`) that is relatively new for Bayesian Additive Regression Trees. I attempted to initially install using `pip` as I normally would and suggested [here](https://pypi.org/project/bartpy/#files). However, this led to me installing the package but none of the necessary files were contained in it. I can import the package but none of the inner modules are available so it is useless.

I'm not sure if I went wrong in this processes. I attempted a few other way including downloading the `.whl` file but got the same result. Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/JakeColtman/bartpy) where the package is set up.

If anyone one could point me in the right direction of going from download to set up (using anaconda's Jupyter notebooks) that would be amazing!

**Edit:**
In `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages` I have the following:

```
bartpy-0.0.1.dist-info
   --RECORD
   --INSTALLER
   --METADATA
   --WHEEL
   --top_level.txt
   --metadata.json
   --DESCRIPTION.rst
```

I assume this file is suppose to aid me, but I am unsure where to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

`pip install git+https://github.com/JakeColtman/bartpy`

cheers

If you use anaconda, make sure that the right `pip` is called (namely the one in `<anaconda-folder>/bin`)

If you cannot import it then it is not installed at the right place. Does `import bartpy` work? and if not, do (from your python command line or even better a jupyter notebook to be sure it is installed at the right place)

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install bartpy`
```

[EDIT]

After a closer look, it seems like the package is not well configured. How I was able to solve this (yes it's ugly and more a hack that a real fix but it should be easy to fix, this technique will allow you to be up and running though):

From shell:

```
git clone <repo-url>
```

In your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("location of the local repo")
from bartpy import ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I attempted this and the package downloaded as the file in the edit of my question. How do I turn that into a python module I can utilize. For example, trying to call `from bartpy.sklearn import SklearnModel`

Comment: Thanks @qmeeus -- looks like it is in the right place and all requirements are satisfied. `import bartpy` does work, but when I attempt to call the modules of the bartpy I get an error that that file is not contained in bartpy

Comment: check the github, then try to `from bartpy.sklearnmodel import SklearnModel` or use tab completion in jupyter :D (and accept the answer if it is solved ;) )

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried this multiple times and gotten a Module Not Found Error. So still not solved. From my experience there must be more in the package file than is showing up in what I have installed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have conda on your path:

```
conda install git
pip install git+git://github....
```

This should work.

Tested:

```
conda create --name snakes python=3.5
conda activate snakes
conda install git pip
pip install git+git://github.com/scrappy/scrappy@master
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This adds a file `bartpy.egg-link` to my `site-pacakges` folder, but doesn't seem to download the package. When I call `import bartpy.sklearnmodel` I get a module not found error.

Comment: Oh the -e gets only the egg. Updated and tested. I have tested the above and it worked:

Comment: I have no doubt this works for you. Mine says successfully built, but "stored in directory: /private/var/folders/ty....". 1) Not sure where that even is in my directory and 2) shouldnt that be in the anaconda/.../site-packages folder?? How do I change that?

Comment: I think you are having issues with which pip is used for your installation. Try which pip if in Unix where pip in Windows!

Comment: Okay that helps...using Mac though

Comment: Is that the pip from the Python version you are using?

Comment: Looks like I'm using the right pip. I think it may be a problem with the package itself (?) in that there are no contents to the package itself.

Comment: You can see in the github clearly the available modules and uses, but everything you have said as worked, it imports into my notebook, but doesn't contain any modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186557/discussion-between-prayson-w-daniel-and-a-powell).